# Can clone and pull from private GitHub repository, but can't pull

Tags: git, github

I started up the PC this morning, expecting to be able to work as normal on a Visual Studio project using the Git extension. I made no config changes whatsoever between the last push and when I last had the solution open.

Then, after trying to push some more commits I had made, I get the error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

I thought that there might have been some problem with Visual Studio, so I tried to push from GitHub Desktop, and I get the same error essentially but through the GUI: "Authentication failed".

I, of course, searched up my issue here, and most of the time, what I read involved changing the URL from HTTPS to SSH or vice versa.

I created my private/public SSH keys and added the public one to my GitHub account. I saw that when using `git remote -v`, fetch used SSH while push used HTTPS, so I changed push to use SSH.

I tried to push from the Git Bash console, and after some hanging, it gave me the exact same error as before. Even when cloning the same repository to a different local folder, the same authentication issue is thrown.

I'm the sole administrator of the repository - it's under my user account, no organisations whatsoever. Nothing else comes to mind what I am meant to do to fix this.

Help?

**EDIT:**
To clarify, my error does not include the common error: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing anything, you can test both access with:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
git ls-remote https://github.com/<you>/<yourRepo>
```

The first one will use your default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key: make sure id_rsa.pub is registered to your remote GitHub account.

[GitHub Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) reported a "Git Operations degradation" earlier today, so make sure to check if the issue persists.

Comment: I believe it was the degradation, as I was able to commit from the VS solution some time later.